# Algorithm for standardizing curves

Tags: low-dimensional-topology

Let $F$ be a surface of genus $g$ that is decorated with $g-$many $\alpha$ curves (in red) and $g-$many $\beta$ curves (in blue). If we like, we can take each curve to be non-separating. Now suppose that $\alpha'$ is an entirely different collection of $g-$many non-separating red curves. Is there necessarily a homeomorphism $\phi:F\to F$ which takes $\alpha$ to $\alpha'$? Is it unique?

If so, is there an algorithm to compute what the new blue curves will be? Something like cutting up the original surface by the red curves and keeping track of intersections.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect you want more assumptions, such as $F\setminus (\alpha_1\cup ...\cup \alpha_g)$ and  $F\setminus (\alpha'_1\cup ...\cup \alpha'_g)$ are connected. Otherwise, there are obvious counter-examples. If you assume this, then such $\phi$ does exist. Also, your curves $\beta$ do not seem to play any role.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the question is, what *happens* to the given blue curves. But this question only makes sense if there is a unique homeomorphism taking $\alpha$ to $\alpha'$. I meant to say this, but I didn't: I want the red curves to be pairwise disjoint. Same with the blue. 

In any case, I now see that this is not true. Sending $g$ curves to any other $g$ curves of the same type can be achieved by infinitely many distinct homeomorphisms.